Merge rows from source dynamic table to destination static table only if the destination doesn't have the source row based on a column?
I have a huge dynamic source table that is continually getting populated with new data. In it there's an ID column whose value can appear over multiple rows over time in the source dynamic table.
Is there a way to scan the source dynamic table, taking only the first row for each ID found, and then writing that to the destination only once? The destination table would be initially empty, but I'm hoping that there's some way to have new rows in the source to be checked if they exist already in the destination based on the ID, and only write them to the destination if that ID is not already in the source?
What I'm struggling with is that if the source is huge, how can I avoid using something like row number/partitioning on the ID every single time - the cost must be excessive and impractical to run constantly?
Any advice would be very much appreciated, maybe someone else has come across this use case already? Thank you very much!
CREATE TABLE example_table (
    id VARCHAR(6),
    event_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    col1 VARCHAR(50),
    col2 INT
);

INSERT INTO example_table (id, event_timestamp, col1, col2) VALUES
('834726', '2024-08-15 10:00:00', 'First entry', 100),
('834726', '2024-08-15 11:00:00', 'Second entry', 200),
('834726', '2024-08-15 12:00:00', 'Third entry', 300),
('834726', '2024-08-15 13:00:00', 'Fourth entry', 400);

In the example above, assume that those 4 rows are coming in over time in that order, and assume that there are billions of rows, all of which have their own ids that may or may not have duplicates like the 4 above.
Which I'm hoping to end up with is that only the first row
('834726', '2024-08-15 10:00:00', 'First entry', 100),
would be written to a destination table, that has the same structure as the first source table

Hi can you please give a DDL and some sample data with the expected output.

Hi Himanshu, thanks for commenting, I've added some DDL - where I'm coming from is that the source table is not static, new data is added all the time, in real time - so it's not really about just a running a query to get the first row from the block above, it's how to deal with new data coming in all the time, maybe with the id already in the destination, and with the idea that the destination at first will be empty and need processing of everything already in the source to get the first row of any IDs found.

I think a problem is that if I try to use something like a merge statement in snowflake, the problem would be that in the initial case, when the destination table is empty, and there is no date column populated in that destination, all rows would be selected as new rows to merge into the destination table. And the source table is so big that it seems impractical to use row number to partition by the id to get the first row of each ID

Hi Rob, to have an correct update you need to uniquely identify the rows as that will help if you use Merge or Update, can you identify the rows uniquely in the source and target ?

I think in this case it the unique part would be the id and event_timestamp combination - but the problem is, it's not that I need to add each one as a unique row, but rather if the row with a new id shows up, then only add it once. I might be misunderstanding it, but what I think happens is that in snowflake, if I have an initially empty table that I want to merge into, and I have a source table that has the data i need to de-duplicate, then all of the rows from the source will get written, as they'll not be in the destination?
